# Lightning component: Invalid Literal Value[1,1]: Javascript :Getting the below error at random when opening the component in ipad salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning, javascript, create-component, dynamiccomponent

i have created a lightning component and that component is dynamically created and called from another component using 
 `$A.createComponent(
dynamicComponent,`

I am getting the below error at random instances whenever i am opening the component from ipad salesforce 1 app.

Any inputs regarding why i am facing such issue at random???
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Invalid Literal Values issue occur in component JS when there is type mismatch between data sent and received between components. I was facing this issue as the value set in the attribute at do Init was of type Object and value sent was of type string.